# Android Studio with AndroidAnnotations NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I have an app with Android annotations that is giving me a NoClassDefFoundError when I try to run it.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br.socialcondo.app.rest.services.UserService_
```

In the annotations log I can see that this class is generated:

```
Note: Generating class: br.socialcondo.app.rest.services.UserService_
```

What I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Sharing build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    apt
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 30

        versionName "2.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("xxx")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "devs"
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "br.socialcondo.app"
        }

        development {
            applicationId "br.socialcondo.app"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'br.socialcondo.app'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '11.0.2'
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Google Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Google Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    //
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile project(':libraries:caldroid')
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper:urlimageviewhelper:1.0.4'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.02@aar'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: you need the android annotations dependency

Comment: I have it in my build.gradle dependencies: `apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'`

Comment: can you share the build.gradle

Comment: build.gradle added to question

Comment: Why `configurations { apt }` block is needed? Otherwise your script seems to be fine.

Comment: @Joqus can you share the root gradle as well?

Comment: @WonderCsabo root gradle included ;)

Comment: I don't know about `configurations { apt }`, it was a colleague put this in the script. May it be the source of the error?

Comment: Can you paste your annotations log?

Comment: @Joqus i am not sure, but trying to remove it should not hurt. But i do not know what is the problem, the gradle scripts seems to be fine. I think the files are correctly generated, but for some reason they are not packaged into the APK.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, the problem is with `multiDexEnabled true`. It is only supported on Android 5 natively. So I need a library for this to run in older versions. I found the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

It is only supported on Android 5 natively. So I need a library for this 
to run in older versions. I found the fix.

Comment: Good catch. I hope you already figured it out, but you have to use the [Multidex Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex).

Comment: @Joqus I'm using Multidex Support Library but I still get  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I had to extend my application from MultiDexApplication or define it in the manifest as per https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle , it is not enough to have the multidex library in the classpath.

Comment: @MnemonicFlow Glad you found the fix